# Using Other Programmers Custom Controls

Tags: dll, user-controls, controls, web, custom-server-controls

I am using Scott Mitchell's textBox Characters and Words counter control, i downloaded it from the website https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ and unzipped it to my desktop. then in VWD Express 2008, i created a new tab in the Toolbox, i chose the *.dll from the unzipped folder, i used the control, all is fine (try it, i recommend it) but when i backed up my code, copied the site, and tried to run it on another computer, i got a bunch of error all indicating that its looking for the dll file on my desktop, but when i checked under my bin folder in my website directory, the dll is there...
Help Plz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the properties of the reference you'll probably find that the path to the reference is incorrect.

I have often found that the quickest way of fixing the problem is to open the project file with notepad and correct the path to the reference.

Comment: You mean opening each page.aspx where i used the control??? and checking it where exactly?

Comment: No, the reference to the assembly (dll) containing the control

Comment: In VWD i clicked on my Bin folder and in Properties->Path it shows the folder where my project is, but when i move the website to another computer and try to run it it still shows an error that its looking for the dlls on the other computers Desktop...HELP